Woocommerce checkout changing subscriptions next payment date
So I use this code to change the next payment date with an extra 2 months
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_first_renewal_payment_time', 'rem_check_renewal_date', 10, 4);
    function rem_check_renewal_date($first_renewal_timestamp, $product_id, $from_date_param, $timezone='site'){
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        if($product->get_attribute('payment-type') != "Monthly"){
            $first_renewal_timestamp = strtotime("+2 months", $first_renewal_timestamp);
        }
        return $first_renewal_timestamp;
    }

    function push_subscriptions_to_14_months($subscription, $order, $recurring_cart) {
        // Check is  not a monthly subscription
        if($subscription->get_billing_period() != 'month'){

        
            // Change first payment to 14 months time
            $new_dates = array(

                'next_payment' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+14 months', time()))
            );

            $subscription->update_dates($new_dates, 'site');
        }
        return $subscription;
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_subscription_created', 'push_subscriptions_to_14_months', 10, 3);

This used to work great. Now for some reason, when I go to checkout, it shows the correct date (+2 months) until the ajax refreshes. Then it shows the original 12 months date. Does anyone know of a way to either override the ajax output, or change where ajax is getting its information from?


I've tried and failed with chatgpt, it added basic error log writing in, which showed the correct dates. I don't know much about ajax with woocommerce so I'm out of my depths with this one
Thanks

Contact plugin devs. If you use block checkout these hooks may not work. Try with checkout shortcode and see if that fixes it.
